# Remove Indexpaths of UITableView that are off screen - indexPath.row is greater than the size of my array

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsindexpath

Is it possible to remove indexpaths of UITableView that are off screen? My case calls for it, and I can't seem to find any methods or answers to remove an `IndexPath.row` that is off screen. I dont need to remove a cell, but only the indexPaths that are visible cells should remain.

Does this make sense?

Sorry I can't provide any code because I dont know where to start.

Answer (score 2):

in iOS6, a new UITableViewDelegate function was introduced that does just this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didEndDisplayingCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

You can use this something like this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didEndDisplayingCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   if ([tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows indexOfObject:indexPath] == NSNotFound)
   {
    // This indeed is an indexPath no longer visible
    // Do something to this non-visible cell...
   }
}
```

Comment: I am trying to get the cell and indexpaths that are not visible to be removed, that is my goal, but i can't figure out how. Do you have any ideas how your suggestion could be expanded?

Comment: I did not have any requirement to use this method so i can't help you with coding. but you can try to remove indexPath within this method because it have reference of that cell which are not visible anymore.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `UITableView` properly and dequeueing cells using the method...

```
[tableView dequeueCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"blah" indexPath:indexPath];
```

then this will already be happening.

The tableview manages which cells are on screen. If you have 1000 rows in your table but only 10 rows on screen at a time then you will only ever have 10 cell objects in memory as those ten are reused for the rows that come onto the screen when others are scrolled off the screen.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. If i could point you to a previous question that I am trying to find a solution for it might further emphasis the problem I am having with the indexpaths.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25388836/forget-remove-reset-cells-that-are-off-the-screen-uitableview